# How can we change naming convention of foreign keys in DB in EF Code First CTP5?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

I am using Entity framework Code First CTP5 and I am trying to find a way to add a convention to change how foreign keys name are generated.  Here is an example:

```
public class Lead
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // A lot of other fields
    public virtual User AssignedTo { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

Lead can be associated to a user.  The field generated in the DB for AssignedTo in the table Leads is called UserId.

My model is completely independent from entity framework.  So I don't want to use attributes from EF.  I would like to use the conventions if possible name the field AssignedToUserId for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would be possible with pluggable conventions but you can use fluent API to achieve it:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Lead>()
                .HasRequired(l => l.AssignedTo)
                .WithMany()
                .IsIndependent()
                .Map(c => c.MapKey(u => u.Id, "AssignedToUserId"));
}
```

Comment: Yep this is what I am doing right now.  But I don't want to have to do that everytime I add a new relation :).